# Python Ping Response Time

Tags: python, ping, icmp

I have seen many examples of how to determine the status of a host using python but I cannot seem to figure out how to send the response time in milliseconds to a var.

```
import time
start = time.time()
result = ping_host(hostname)
duration = time.time() - start
```

So I should replace ping_host or hostname?

Answer (score 4):

From a high level, you can just use the `time` module. `time.time` gives you seconds since epoch, usually with at least millisecond precision.

```
start = time.time()
result = ping_host(hostname)
duration = time.time() - start
```

`duration` is then a variable holding the time your ping took with the highest precision `time` affords.

Comment: @sealfab, it depends on what your pinging logic looks like. `ping_host` above is just a stub. Nonetheless, a reasonable seeming interface would have you pass in the hostname to the function, as I've done above.

Comment: But if i replace ping_host with an ip or hostname it returns a syntax error

Comment: I don't know what your pinging implementation looks like. `ping_host` above is just an example. If you want to share your implementation, we could help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the external utility `ping` and parse its output, try something like

```py
import subprocess

for ip in list_of_ip_addresses_or_host_names:
    result = subprocess.run(
        # Command as a list, to avoid shell=True
        ['ping', '-c', '1', ip],
        # Expect textual output, not bytes; let Python .decode() on the fly
        text=True,
        # Shorthand for stdout=PIPE stderr=PIPE etc etc
        capture_output=True,
        # Raise an exception if ping fails (maybe try/except it separately?)
        check=True)
    for line in result.stdout.splitlines():
        # Sample output from my ping:
        # PING hostname.example.com (10.9.8.7): 56 data bytes
        # 64 bytes from 10.130.42.70: icmp_seq=0 ttl=60 time=11.190 ms
        # 
        # --- hostname.example.com ping statistics ---
        # 1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
        # round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 11.190/11.190/11.190/0.000 ms
        if "icmp_seq" in line:
            timing = line.split('time=')[-1].split(' ms')[0]
            print(ip, timing)
```

You could perhaps tweak the `-c` parameter to send more than one packet if you like, and then you should probably parse out the round-trip min/avg/max/stdev line instead.

The `split` indices take some care to avoid an IndexError if the expected string is not found, but then of course the result will still be bogus; this could be made tighter e.g. by using a regular expression, or just require the `time=` and  `ms` strings to be in the line too before attempting to parse it.

`subprocess.run()` is the primary modern API to the `subprocess` package; you could use the legacy function `subprocess.check_output` as well, or raw `subprocess.Popen()` if you really want to do all the necessary plumbing yourself (but probably don't, especially if you don't understand what "necessary plumbing" means here).